# All chains in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Which algorithm I need to use to find all possible chains maximal length?

```
1) Main->Foo1->Foo2->Foo3->Foo4
2) Main->Foo2->Foo3->Foo4
3) Main->Foo6->Foo7
```

Find all possible paths in the graph and then exclude all that are less than the largest?

[image]

Comment: If the graph is topologically sorted, and has a single root, then a DFS should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can go backwards from the leaf nodes.

The goal is to **label every node** with the length of the longest path that starts at this node.

- First, label all leaves (Foo4 and Foo7 in your example) as `1`;
- While there is a node `u` such that all children of `u` have been labeled:

  - Label `u` as `1 + max(labels of children of u)`

*Note: this assumes there are no cycles in the graph. Otherwise, nodes which are part of a cycle will never get a label.*

Now, the **length of the longest path** is marked on your root node. If you have more than one root node or don't know who the root node is: find the node with highest label.

To **retrace the longest path**:

- Start at the root node
- While the current node has at least one child:

  - Move to the child who has the highest label

With your examples, the labels will be:

```
Foo4, Foo7: 1
Foo3, Foo6: 2
Foo2:       3
Foo1:       4
Main:       5
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume the graph is a DAG (directed acyclic graph), find all of it's entry-points (vertexes not having any inbound edge). Scan the graph (preferably using BFS and not DFS, since we want to get step by step over the tree's depth in order to easily determine the maximal one), starting the scan from each of the entry points, and memoize the depth scanned on each step. From there it should be easy.

**Clarification:**
If the graph isn't a DAG, the question is pointless since cyclic paths are infinite.